# How to render Jade code on browser?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, pug

I'm new to Jade and I want to know How to run the .jade file , I'm using Node.js and i installed the jade node module .. what's the next step to run the code and find it in the browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You must run your Node.js server on the command line.

```
$ node app.js
```

2) Go to your browser and use the port number that your server is running on. Generally you want to console.log the port number in your app.js file so the port is displayed on the command line.

```
localhost:3000
```

3) https://github.com/visionmedia/jade for examples and more documentation to get you off the ground.